# Filter array in Typescript using functional programing [filter, map, some, reduce etc]

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, functional-programming, rxjs

I'm trying to work with functional programming

I have two arrays

```
arr1=[{prodId:2}{prodId:4}]

arr2=[{id:1, name:"Test1"},
      {id:2, name:"Test2"},
      {id:3, name:"Test3"},
      {id:4, name:"Test4"},
      {id:5, name:"Test5"}]
```

using a combination of

> filter, map, some, reduce functions

I want to extract items from arr2

```
where arr2.id === arr1.prodId
```

my output arr would be:

```
  [{id:2, name:"Test2"},
  {id:4, name:"Test4"}]
```

I'm trying to avoid forEach and use functional programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `filter` method in combination with `includes` and `map`.

```js
let arr1=[{prodId:2},{prodId:4}], arr2=[{id:1, name:"Test1"}, {id:2, name:"Test2"}, {id:3, name:"Test3"}, {id:4, name:"Test4"}, {id:5, name:"Test5"}];
let ids = arr1.map(({prodId}) => prodId);
let result = arr2.filter(({id}) => ids.includes(id));
console.log(result);
```

Another approach is to use `some` method.

```js
let arr1=[{prodId:2},{prodId:4}], arr2=[{id:1, name:"Test1"}, {id:2, name:"Test2"}, {id:3, name:"Test3"}, {id:4, name:"Test4"}, {id:5, name:"Test5"}];

let result = arr2.filter(({id}) => arr1.some(({prodId}) => prodId == id));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can extract the inner `map` function to avoid to compute the operation for every iteration.

Comment: The `some` approach is preferred IMO the intent is clearer than the `includes` version.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions using `.includes`, `.find`, or `.some` are array operations and cost linear time. When used inside `.filter`, another linear time operation, the result is a quadratic time computation. If the input lists are large, this impact is not insignificant.

Instead, first collect the ids to match in a Set then take advantage of constant time lookup in the `filter` -

```js
const arr1 = 
  [ { prodId: 2 }
  , { prodId: 4 }
  ]

const arr2 =
  [ { id:1, name:"Test1" }
  , { id:2, name:"Test2" }
  , { id:3, name:"Test3" }
  , { id:4, name:"Test4" }
  , { id:5, name:"Test5" }
  ]
      
const find = (whitelist, list) =>
{ const ids =
    new Set (whitelist.map(x => x.prodId)) // create a set
    
  return list.filter(x => ids.has(x.id)) // Set#has uses constant time
}

console.log(find(arr1,arr2))
// [ { id: 2, name: "Test2" }, { id: 4, name: "Test4" } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for.

```js
arr1=[{prodId:2},{prodId:4}]

arr2=[{id:1, name:"Test1"},
      {id:2, name:"Test2"},
      {id:3, name:"Test3"},
      {id:4, name:"Test4"},
      {id:5, name:"Test5"}]


      

    let k=arr2.reduce((o,a)=>{
      if(arr1.map(a=>a.prodId).indexOf(a.id)!=-1)
      {
         o.push(a)
      }
        return o;
      },[])
console.log(k)
```